# JPanel - Error changing background color of a JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I have written the following code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test extends JFrame{
    
    public Test() {
        this.setTitle("Test");
        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel() {
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g.fillOval(100, 100, 100, 100);
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100);
            }
        };
        jPanel.setSize(500, 500);
        jPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        this.add(jPanel);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setSize(500, 500);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
    }
}
```

I want to draw a circle, the line, and change the background color of the screen to red, but when I run the program the screen looks as follows:
[image: Screen]

Where is the error in the code?. Tank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, don't override `paint`, but `paintComponent`.

Then, the javadoc of `setBackground` says :

> Direct subclasses of JComponent must override paintComponent to honor
>   this property.

So calling this method will do nothing by itself in your case, unless you call the `paintComponent` of the parent class (or paint the background yourself, but that would be overkill).

In any case it is advised to call `super.paintComponent`, because the parent implementation may perform some cleaning or other useful operations.

Here is a modified version of your code that takes all of this into account :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public Test() {
        this.setTitle("Test");
        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(final WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
                // call parent method
                super.paintComponent(g);

                // OR paint background yourself :
                // g.setColor(getBackground());
                // g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());


                // paint other things
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g.fillOval(100, 100, 100, 100);
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100);
            }
        };
        jPanel.setSize(500, 500);
        jPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        this.add(jPanel);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setSize(500, 500);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help, do you recommend any book, web page, or another resource to learn about Java GUI development?

Comment: @Lemark : the tutorial from Oracle is a good start : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/